# Apps Script to allow user to send data to spreadsheet that they cannot view?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am sending spreadsheets to various people. I want them to enter some data into the spreadsheet and then click a "submit" button to send that data to another spreadsheet, where I'll collect data from multiple users.

The people who are sending data will not have view/edit access to the spreadsheet where data is being aggregated.

Right now I have copies set up with the "submit" button and associated code. However, I think it won't work if the person clicking the "submit" button doesn't have edit access to the spreadsheet where the data is being sent.

Is there some way to give them write-only access to the aggregation spreadsheet?

If not, is there some other workaround that might help? Perhaps I could go through a form somehow?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your goal, for example, how about using Web Apps as a wrapper? When the button is clicked, the script requests to the Web Apps by sending the values. At Web Apps, the values are put to the specific Spreadsheet that the user cannot view and edit. How about this? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Write permissions without view permissions are impossible. Submission of sheets via a Google form which triggers a script that does your post-aggregation would be possible. As a different workaround, on submit you could give the user temporary write access using [Drive File permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-sharing) which you can then revoke again for the user at the end of the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 ways I know of to do this, all kind of janky:

1) Instead of a submit button, you can use an installable onEdit() trigger. The on edit will run as the user who installed the trigger instead of the the user triggering the edit.

2) Have them submit the spreadsheet into a google form as a document upload, then have the form analyze the data on submit.

3) Use webhooks. Deploy the spreadsheet as a [web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) and have the button send a [urlFetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/) request with the data or sheets id for processing.